# Exporting data APIs?

Tags: rest-api, bulk-api

What's the best way to programatically **export** data in a **custom object** from Salesforce?

Like with the Bulk API 2.0, but to automatically export data daily from Salesforce to a system in another server. I'll want to import the object content into a MySQL Database to be used in a server application.

I'm **not** looking for a commercial service or app, but an API.

Please point to the relevant documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a similar requirement to export data from specific objects for audit purposes. we asked the external system(middleware) to use bulk query(bulk api) to export data from salesforce and send it to external system.

Below documentation link has more details.A bulk query can retrieve up to 15 GB of data, divided into 15 1-GB files. The data formats supported are CSV, XML, and JSON.

Read [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_bulk_query_intro.htm)